# Android WebView download image in a path as Cache

Tags: android, caching, webview

I'm trying to using `WebView` to show my blog posts in Android.

I can save `HTML` text in sqlite DateBase for next use when user is offline but the problem is saving images in a directory when user is online .
for next visit if image found in specified directory , so use it ! , else download and cache for future uses !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to enable the WebView app cache:

```
// Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (cm != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
} else {
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
}
```

You will need to add `.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` permissions.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) you can find more info about all the `WebSettings`.